# Baked-in or efficient knockout default/optional observable

Tags: knockout.js

I'm needing to set several values on my view model, which may or may not have corresponding values on parameters passed in to the viewModel constructor.

I am familiar with jQuery plugin default objects and merging with passed-in options, and I'm wondering if there's something similar for observables in Knockout.

The following works for a one-off, but I would hate to have to do this for every single message if there are say a dozen or more:

```
export function viewModel(params) {
    const vm = {};
    vm.messageOne = params.hasOwnProperty('messageOne') ? params.messageOne : 'My default message';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to merge the two:

```
function ViewModel(params) {
  // All default properties go here:
  const vm = { messageOne: "My Default Message" };

  // Overwrite properties that are in `params`
  Object.assign(vm, params);

  /* ... */
}
```

If you have an ordered set of messages, they should come in an array rather than an object with keys.

If you just want to transform an object in to one with observable properties, you can use the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin